# Why is my API key visible when using next.js with environment variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, environment-variables, next.js

I followed next.js documentation and added a custom api key on now server.

The problem is that when i run `now dev` and go to the sources tab, I can see my api key there.

[image]

The api key is saved in `.env.build` file, here is my code:

**index.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const axios = require('axios');

import Nav from '../src/components/Nav';
import Head from '../src/components/Head';
import Movies from '../src/components/movies';

const key = process.env.API_KEY;

const index = () => {
  const [currentMovies, setCurrentMovies] = useState([]);

  const getTopMovies = async url => {
    const fetchData = await axios.get(url).then(response => {
      const [...data] = response.data.results;
      setCurrentMovies({ data: data });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getTopMovies(
      `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2019-12-12&primary_release_date.lte=2020-02-22&api_key=${key}`
    );
  }, []);

  if (currentMovies.data === undefined) {
    console.log('Loading...');
  } else {
    console.log(currentMovies.data);
  }
```

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    API_KEY: process.env.API_KEY
  }
};
```

**now.config.json**

```
{
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "API_KEY": "@api-key-moviedb"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NextJS implements environment variables with [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) from Webpack. All the variables used with `process.env` are replaced with variables in `.env` in compile time. From the docs:

> Next.js will replace process.env.customKey with 'my-value' at **build** time.

Unlike on the server side, NextJS is still a client side framework for running JavaScript in the browser and as it stands there are no ways of hiding these keys from the browser.

If you have to hide the key, then you would have to add a server (or a serverless function).

You can add an API endpoint and call it from the frontend, which would connect to 3rd party service and return the fetched data.

One of the ways to do that is to add `.env` and load it to Node process with [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

**.env**

```
API_KEY=@api-key-moviedb
```

**next.config.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  /* config options here */
};
```

**Usage**

```
process.env.API_KEY
```

This way your API key won't be exposed.

[Next.js with dotenv example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-dotenv)

[API routes in Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

Comment: Where is `@api-key-moviedb` coming from here?

Comment: @ZackShapiro That's a `<put-your-api-key-here>` slot

Comment: Next.js automatically supports Environment Variable loading as of Next.js 9.4. You can read more about it in the blog post.

Visit the documentation to learn how to use Environment Variables support in Next.js 9.4+ and the Environment Variables Example to see it on action.